# add a constraint to ipywidgets.datepicker, only allow value between two dates

Tags: python, datepicker, widget, ipywidgets

I'm using the DatePicker widget from ipywidgets. I was wondering if I could set some constraints for the day the user picks. Would it be possible to limit the user to only pick a day between `datetime.date(2020, 2, 10)` and `datetime.date(2020, 2, 16)`?

Currently my code looks like this:

```
dp = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False
)
```

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I had the same requirement. Didn't find anything in the official documentation, but I have found a hack using javascript to set the min and max tags on the generated html input box that works:

```py
%matplotlib widget

import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

date_picker = widgets.DatePicker(
    description='Pick a Date',
    disabled=False,
)
date_picker.add_class("start-date")

script = Javascript("\
                const query = '.start-date > input:first-of-type'; \
                document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('min', '2020-12-01'); \
                document.querySelector(query).setAttribute('max', '2021-01-01'); \
        ")

display(date_picker)
display(script)
```